# add drop down filter to table jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'd just like to add a filter to my table to filter the deals by free gift... Not sure how to do it.

I have made the drop down box for the filter but how do i populate it with the data it needs to be filtered by without cheating - I need it to actually check the table for the filterable data as the tables are created in php and I cant manually make the filter preset with filterable options as I have many many tables on my site.

As you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/51Le6o06/26/ as an example this is what is currently happening - each row contains a child row and there is also paging and there are two tables as it must work with multiple tables on the same page.

So how do I create this filter?

jQuery

```
jQuery.fn.sortPaging = function(options) {
    var defaults = {
        pageRows: 4
    };
    var settings = $.extend(true, defaults, options);
    return this.each(function() {

        var container = $(this);
        var tableBody = container.find('.internalActivities > tbody');
        var dataRows = [];
        var currentPage = 1;
        var maxPages = 1;
        var buttonMore = container.find('.seeMoreRecords');
        var buttonLess = container.find('.seeLessRecords');
        var buttonFree = container.find('.filter-free');
        var tableRows = [];
        var maxFree = 0;
        var filterFree = buttonFree.is(':checked');
        function displayRows() {
            tableBody.empty();
            var displayed = 0;
            $.each(dataRows, function(i, ele) {
                if( !filterFree || (filterFree && ele.isFree) ) {
                    tableBody.append(ele.thisRow).append(ele.nextRow);
                    displayed++;
                    if( displayed >= currentPage*settings.pageRows ) {
                        return false;
                    };
                };
            });
        };
        function checkButtons() {
            buttonLess.toggleClass('element_invisible', currentPage<=1);
            buttonMore.toggleClass('element_invisible', filterFree ? currentPage>=maxFreePages : currentPage>=maxPages);
        };
        function showMore() {
            currentPage++;
            displayRows();
            checkButtons();
        };
        function showLess() {
            currentPage--;
            displayRows();
            checkButtons();
        };
        function changedFree() {
            filterFree = buttonFree.is(':checked');
            if( filterFree && currentPage>maxFreePages ) {
                currentPage=maxFreePages;
            };
            displayRows();
            checkButtons();
        };

        tableBody.find('.product-data-row').each(function(i, j) {
            var thisRow = $(this);
            var nextRow = thisRow.next();
            var amount = parseFloat(thisRow.find('.amount').text().replace(/£/, ''));
            var isFree = thisRow.find('.free').length;
            maxFree += isFree;
            dataRows.push({
                amount: amount,
                thisRow: thisRow,
                nextRow: nextRow,
                isFree: isFree
            });
        })

        dataRows.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.amount - b.amount;
        });
        maxPages = Math.ceil(dataRows.length/settings.pageRows);
        maxFreePages = Math.ceil(maxFree/settings.pageRows);

        tableRows = tableBody.find("tr");

        buttonMore.on('click', showMore);
        buttonLess.on('click', showLess);
        buttonFree.on('change', changedFree);

        displayRows();
        checkButtons();

    })

};

$('.sort_paging').sortPaging();
```

HTML

```
<h1>Table sorting on page load with paging</h1>

<div class="sort_paging">

    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" class="filter-free" /> Free Handset
        <select class="filter-gift">
          <!-- Options must be filled by jQuery from HTML $(.information)-->
        </select>
    </p>

    <table class="internalActivities">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>head1</th>
                <th>head2</th>
                <th>head3</th>
                <th>head4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="handsetcost">£364.00 upfront</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£10.10 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free TV
                </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£40.40 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free TV
                </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£30.30 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free TV
                </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£16.04 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free XBOX
                </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="handsetcost">£134.00 upfront</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£12.19 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free XBOX
                </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="handsetcost">£120.00 upfront</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£14.22 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free XBOX
                </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£50.22 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free XBOX
                </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£10.33 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free PS4
                </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£40.45 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free PS4
                </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="handsetcost">£200.00 upfront</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£30.84 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free PS4
                </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£16.14 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free PS4
                </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£12.10 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free Biscuits
                </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£14.02 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free Biscuits
                </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£50.88 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free Biscuits
                </p></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="button" class="seeMoreRecords" value="More">
    <input type="button" class="seeLessRecords" value="Less">

</div>

<h2>Second table below</h2>

<div class="sort_paging">

    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" class="filter-free" /> Free Handset
        <select class="filter-gift">
          <!-- Options must be filled by jQuery from HTML $(.information)-->
        </select>
    </p>

    <table class="internalActivities">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>head1</th>
                <th>head2</th>
                <th>head3</th>
                <th>head4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="handsetcost">£364.00 upfront</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£10.10 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free TV
                </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£40.40 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free TV
                </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£30.30 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free TV
                </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£16.04 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free XBOX
                </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="handsetcost">£134.00 upfront</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£12.19 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free XBOX
                </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="handsetcost">£120.00 upfront</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£14.22 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free XBOX
                </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£50.22 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free XBOX
                </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£10.33 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free PS4
                </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£40.45 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free PS4
                </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="handsetcost">£200.00 upfront</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£30.84 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free PS4
                </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£16.14 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free PS4
                </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£12.10 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free Biscuits
                </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£14.02 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free Biscuits
                </p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£50.88 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%"><p class="information">Free Biscuits
                </p></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="button" class="seeMoreRecords" value="More">
    <input type="button" class="seeLessRecords" value="Less">

</div>
```

Comment: Why not use JQuery UI ?

Comment: How im new to jQuery

Comment: So do you want to learn JQuery UI or just get the answer for this ?

Comment: both im learning jQuery on codecademy.com at the minute

Comment: Cannot understand what do you want. May be some illustration by images?

Comment: its pretty clear mate "I'd just like to add a filter to my table to filter the deals by free gift... Not sure how to do it."

Comment: @user1273587 in the drop down box id like to be able to filter each table by free gift what are you unsure about?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/51Le6o06/26/

Comment: filter based on free gift care to explain more into that be specific in a detailed manner

Comment: the filter on the jsfiddle (empty dropdown) should collect filterable data from html table below then populate the drop down like so.. free biscuits, free tv, free ps4, free xbox > and then be able to select a filter and only show the rows which contain that data (inside the child row) as when "Free handset" is selected it only shows rows which contain (free handsets) do you get what I mean guys??

Comment: each row has a child row and I want a filter to filter the class (.information) which contains the free gift e.g. "Free Biscuits" as there are many tables on my website I cant simply hardcode the filter with options - I want the filter to collect the free gifts from the HTML then have them available as an option to filter the table by in the drop down please tell me if you need anymore information

Answer (score 1):

I emulated your case at my end, I am pretty much near to your requirement. Use this template.

Remove your old code completely.
Updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/51Le6o06/39/ .

Make these changes in your html now. There are two places with sort_paging class. Give them tags like this below.

```
<div class="sort_paging" tag="tab1">
<div class="sort_paging" tag="tab2">

 $(document).ready(function () {
    //   Initialize();
    $('.filter-free').click(filterItems);
   })

   function filterItems(e) {
var items = [];
var checked = this.checked;
var table = '';
tableId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('tag')
if (checked) {
    var listItems = "";
    listItems += "<option value='0'> -Select- </option>";
    $('div[tag="' + tableId + '"] table.internalActivities .information').each(function (i) {
        var itm = $(this)[0].innerText;
        if ($.inArray(itm, items) == -1) {
            items.push($(this)[0].innerText);
            listItems += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + $(this)[0].innerText + "</option>";
        }
    });
}
else {
    listItems = "<option value='0'> -Select- </option>";
}
$('div[tag="' + tableId+ '"] .filter-gift').html(listItems);

$('.filter-gift').change(function () {
    var tableIdC = $(this).parent().parent().attr('tag');

    var text = $('div[tag="' + tableIdC + '"] select option:selected')[0].text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r| |)/gm, "");;
        $('div[tag="' + tableIdC + '"] .product-information-row').each(function (i) {
            if ($(this).text().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r| |)/gm, "") == text) {
                $(this).show();
                $(this).prev().show();
                $(this).next().show();
            }
            else {
                $(this).hide();
                $(this).prev().hide();
                $(this).next().hide();
            }
        });           
    });    
 }
     function Initialize(){
// your old code here
jQuery.fn.sortPaging = function(options) {.....
}
```

Comment: yes, you will have to make some changes in that for it to properly work, i just gave some base work

Comment: okk then, let me try. what should do is to learn jquery, simple :)

Comment: I am learning :) but this is quite advanced - i give you the 50 points if you can make it work

Comment: Your default function is ausing problem. If you will remove that and will use my function then you can get what you wanted. I have edited my answer

Comment: does not work @Spark its filtering both tables at the same time which is a major factor as i have multiple tables on the same page also the filter doesn't load any options unless the table is interacted with before hand.

Comment: good work but no cigar I need this to work with my other functions also

Comment: as this does serve as a basis for building the filter though I think its only fair you get the points thanks

Comment: dont worry, i will fix that soon. You will have to give Ids to both the tables or something that can be used to identify two tables differently. How would to like to do that. I will suggest you to have "tag" attribute on both like tag='tab1" and tag='tab2"

Comment: how come you made it so you have to check the wrong filter box?

Comment: both the dropdowns have same classes. thats why its happening.

Comment: this jsfiddle gets around that dont know how but both tables are using the same functions for my sorting, filtering and paging https://jsfiddle.net/51Le6o06/37/

Comment: okki i will make some changes in ur html.. I had asked for your suggestion where should i make change in ur html.

Comment: Hi spark you have solved the problem of filtering each table individually the only problems i face with this is functionality being based on having my checkbox selected "Free Handset" which I use for a seperate filter could you remove that and have the filter options load on page load?

Comment: it also would be cool if the default option - Select - when selected showed all rows instead of hiding the entire table

Comment: ok, 1- you want the dropdown be filled on page load.
2- No filtering be done when - Select - is selected

Comment: I made some changes so it works on page load check it out https://jsfiddle.net/51Le6o06/42/ i only have one problem left - that is the default option -select- when selected it hides the table I want it to show all any ideas how to do it?

Comment: I solved that problem spark can you help me on this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37105299/filtering-hidden-data-pagination-issue-jquery-javascript

Comment: the pagination is the only problem now

Answer (score 0):

Rob Bayliss has developed a script that he offers as a download at http://rbayliss.net/jquery-dropdown-table-filter. It should suit your needs.

```
$('#table_format').ddTableFilter()
```

Comment: this is what I require but im looking for an answer that works with my example on jsfiddle as I have child rows in my tables and a lot of other stuff going on Im unsure weather this will work could you show me the code on jsfiddle using my example?